# Use sim network to detect user current location without GPS or internet in react native

Tags: react-native, gps

I want get  user current Location (just in android) without internet  and send it with SMS. I try with this code in react native :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                let initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
                console.log(initialPosition);
            },
            (error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)),
            {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 2000 }
        );
```

but this code give me this error :

```
error : 3 , Location request timed out
```

and I search in google and also https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/ for this problem and try many ways to solve it , like this :

```
enableHighAccuracy: false
```

or 
remove options param

```
 {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 2000 }
```

or 
remove `maximumAge` and when remove `maximumAge` this work, but when remove it 
device give me last detected user location that maybe is far of user current location

and also try with this library https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service
for last solution and implement library example code :
https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service/tree/master/example

but this code just work well with WIFI and when WIFI is of give me `Time out`  error .

**my question is :**

How can I use sim network to detect user current location without GPS or internet network in react native, that support in many android device and SDK version?

Comment: Any breakthrough?

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to delete maximumAge, just put 0 (maximumAge: 0). If you delete it, then the last position will be cached.
2. And enableHighAccuracy set false.
3. Make more timeout.

[Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation)

> maximumAge (ms) - Is a positive value indicating the maximum age in milliseconds of a possible cached position that is acceptable to return. If set to 0, it means that the device cannot use a cached position and must attempt to retrieve the real current position. If set to Infinity the device will always return a cached position regardless of its age. **Defaults to INFINITY**.

Remember to use permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file

[Manifest.permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission)